# dns display all zone and subfolder

Tags: powershell, cmd, dns, alias, cname

I have to make a programme that list the dns hierarchie
i tried dnscmd but i only find zone not the folder that admin created under.

from mmc it look like this:

[image]

so this cmd

dnscmd domain.foo /enumzones

will only show AC but not agen (wich contain some alias i have to trace)

i'll do this with powershell but any cmd admin will work...

Comment: DNS does not have a concept called a "folder". It is not clear what you're asking for.

Comment: duno realy how this call in code its a "noud " anyway the pics of the mmc talk by it self what i want access.